# error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" after "firebase-tools-instant-win.exe"

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm a new user of firebase.
I try to follow this firebase tuto: [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#3).
This error accure  :

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

[image]

The commands `firebase login` & `firebase projects:list` & `firebase login:ci` works well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veFr0.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIn9b.jpg)

Then, in this part: [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#3)  we have to make a `firebase use --add` in the `web-start` directory in order to make link between working folder and firebase project.

This error occur:

> - "firebase: The term "firebase" is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, file name
>   script or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path exists,
>   Verify that the path is correct and try again.
> - lign 1:1
> - firebase use --add
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (firebase:String) [], CommandNotFoundException        
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
>   ```

This is the firebase tuto's code. Looks like there is something wrong, yet I just added the config.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVcwi.jpg)

My first question is why I have the **"Maximum call stack size exceeded"** error ?

Second one, why `firebase use --add` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem installating nvm v1.1.9 and npm v8.12